# Checking radio buttons based on model values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a survey that can be saved and revisited at a later date, right now the user can save the values which go to the db in the form of a serialized class, then they get retrieved by the controller (if they exist) and added to the view model.

Each question in the survey has 5 possible answers and the questions are generated using a foreach loop from a list within the view model.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to make it so that if the view model list of saved answers isnt null, then automatically check the radio button that corresponds to the value saved in the db.

I've looked around other posts similar to this and they only deal with Yes/No buttons, however I'd need it to compare the radio button value within Model.SavedAnswers[i].Value and check if if they're the same, is this possible?

Example code below as to the structure of my foreach that generates the questions. Saved values are stored in a List, AnswerModel contains a property called value that would be what's getting compared to the radio button value.

```
@foreach (Question m in Model.Questions)
{
    <tr style="background-color: #f1f1f1">
        <td colspan="5">
            @count @m.QuestionText
            @Html.Hidden("Answers[" + (count - 1) + "].QuestionNumber", m.QuestionNumber) 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #fff">
        <td>
            @Html.Label("Strongly Agree")
            @Html.RadioButton("Answers[" + (count - 1) + "].Value", "0", new { id = m.QuestionNumber }) 
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.Label("Agree")
            @Html.RadioButton("Answers[" + (count - 1) + "].Value", "1", new { id = m.QuestionNumber })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.Label("Neither agree nor disagree")
            @Html.RadioButton("Answers[" + (count - 1) + "].Value", "2", new { id = m.QuestionNumber })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.Label("Disagree")
            @Html.RadioButton("Answers[" + (count - 1) + "].Value", "3", new { id = m.QuestionNumber })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.Label("Strongly Disagree")
            @Html.RadioButton("Answers[" + (count - 1) + "].Value", "4", new { id = m.QuestionNumber })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.Label("Don't Know")
            @Html.RadioButton("Answers[" + (count - 1) + "].Value", "5", new { id = m.QuestionNumber })
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="separator" />
    count++;
}
```

Comment: you need to use strongly typed html helper methods for that  check this link https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-radiobutton-radiobuttonfor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code I'm assuming this is the class of `Question`

```
public class Question
{
    public int QuestionNumber { get; set; }
    public int? Value { get; set; }
}
```

What you need is actually another property to keep track of the previous value, which you can compare with when you're getting the post back in your controller, like so:

```
public class Question
{
    public int QuestionNumber { get; set; }
    public int? Value { get; set; }
    public int? PreviousValue { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your view file you'll need a hidden field to make sure the current value will bind as the previous value when the form gets posted back to the controller, something like this:

```
@Html.Hidden("Answers[" + (count - 1) + "].PreviousValue", m.Value)
```

That is all you need, but you may find something odd when your view renders the radio buttons are always empty, i.e. not reflecting the current value. That is because in all your `@Html.RadioButton()` you did not use the other overload for the input which is `RadioButton(string name, object value, bool isChecked)`. Therefore you will need to change all your `@Html.RadioButton()` to include the third parameter which indicates that the radio button will be checked when it is true. Example:

```
@Html.RadioButton("Answers[" + (count - 1) + "].Value", "0", new { id = m.QuestionNumber }, m.Value == 0)
```

when the third parameter `m.Value == 0` returns true it will render the checkbox as checked.